# What's the Difference of Dictionary<string, object> vs. IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>

Tags: c#

MongoDB has these two forms of BsonDocument constructors:

```
BsonDocument(Dictionary<string, object> dictionary);
BsonDocument(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> dictionary);
```

`Dictionary<string, object>` implies the `string` must be unique so is a dictionary.

`IEnumerable` is simply an iteration, `string` not necessarily to be unique, however `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>` means iterable unique value pairs, obviously qualifies for dictionary, so what's the difference?

Comment: A key value pair isn't itself a dictionary.

Comment: Look up Dictionaries and then IEnumerable. Its not too hard.

Comment: Please use proper punctuation - your commas are confusing people!

Comment: "`KeyValuePair<string, object>` is actually a dictionary". No, it's not. In any case, a `KeyValuePair` is *an entry* in a `Dictionary`

Comment: A `Dictionary<string, object>` **is a** `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>` where each key *must* be unique. On the other hand, an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>` **is not necessarily** a `Dictionary<string, object>` nor are its collection of keys guaranteed to be unique. In *both* instances, a `KeyValuePair<string, object>` is a representation of *a single item* within the entire collection (Dictionaries are represented internally by other structures, the public api includes the KeyValuePair struct)

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 agree with the first part. For 2nd part, if **Key** applies to **value** then it's a dictionary, else if **Key** is for the **pair** it isn't a dictionary. Your explanation seems like it applies to the pair, for example `{1:"first"}, {1:"another first"}`, right?

Comment: That would be possible in the second case. There's nothing restricting an IEnumerable from having a duplicated key, unless that IEnumerable is of type dictionary as well

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, in a dictionary, the key is guaranteed to be unique (and the Dictionary will throw an exception if you attempt to add a duplicate).  There is no such guarantee with `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>>`.

Second, Dictionaries are highly optimized for key-based lookups.  There is no such concept in an `IEnumerable`, forcing you to iterate the collection to find your key value pair.

Finally, a Dictionary is a specialized collection of `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` entries, not an individual `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` entry.  In terms of an English dictionary, the Dictionary is the book, whereas the `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` entries are the individual articles.

In an `IEnumerable`, nothing would restrict you from having multiple articles with the same identifier, making it difficult to find your article.  Even worse, the order might be complete nonsense, making finding your article rather slow.

In essence, they are two completely different forms of collections.  The first is (often) a hash set, the second is an array (typically, although the `IEnumerable` interface can obviously be implemented on hash sets such as a dictionary). You choose the data structure for the appropriate task.

Comment: Speaking about `IDictionary<TKer, TValue>`, it's not necessarily to be hash based - sorted array, red-black tree etc. are just one of the possible implemetations. But all other points apply.

Comment: ONE Oxford Dictionary vs. MULTIPLE dictionaries?

Comment: @IvanStoev point well taken.  It was simply an over generalization to help the OP make sense of the differences.  I don't think delving into trees vs sorted arrays would necessarily be wise at this point :).  That said, I'll slightly modify my answer.

Comment: I know :) *Unique keys* and *optimized for fast key lookup* are the key points in your answer. All other is implementation details.

Comment: @IvanStoev it's a great clarifying point and easily incorporated :).  Thanks.

Comment: @Jeb50 you appear to have some kind of resistence against people telling you that a `KeyValuePair` is an ENTRY of a dictionary and thus it is NOT a dictionary itself.

Comment: great explanation, I modified the post with more details.